# How do I stop the automatic refresh of the chatter:feed component every 60 seconds?

Tags: chatter

We have a chatter feed in a visualforce page. The visualforce page is output as a custom console component in our Service Cloud.

The tag in the VF page looks like this:

```
<chatter:feed id="alertfeed" entityId="{!myalertgroup.id}" rendered="true" showPublisher="false"/>
```

The problem is that it automatically refreshes every 60 seconds. We do not want this because

1) it interrupts users when commenting,

2) we have a script that re-renders the feed only when there is a new post, and

3) We think the refreshing might be responsible for a "Network IO suspended" error that users are getting sometimes.

When the refresh runs, this is what appears in the console:

```
CEB EVENT! ns<chatter:publisher> en<onAfterFeedLoad> pld<[object
Object]> exec-time<0> Chatter.js:242 .
```

Our developer has told us that there is no way to prevent this refresh. But I feel like there must be a workaround!